# How to generate Open API specification from existing falcon api?

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, falconframework, openapi-generator

I had an existing RESTful API written in Falcon framework. Currently, I used Sphinx for API documentation. I want to switch to Swagger (now called OpenAPI) and generating the Swagger Specification automatically. After searching on GG for a while, I found a PyPi package falcon-swagger-ui. But it looks like I have to write the specification manually. I want some thing like Sphinx, I can write normal python docs string using some Sphinx template. Now I found p2swagger but dont know how to set up? Can anyone advice what should I do? Thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [falcon-apispec](https://github.com/alysivji/falcon-apispec).

The following short example (modified version of [Falcon Quickstart Example](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/quickstart.html#learning-by-example)) should show how it works.

```
import falcon
from apispec import APISpec
from falcon_apispec import FalconPlugin
import json


class ThingsResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests
        ---
        description: Prints cite from Kant
        responses:
            200:
                description: Cite to be returned
        """
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200  # This is the default status
        resp.body = ('\nTwo things awe me most, the starry sky '
                     'above me and the moral law within me.\n'
                     '\n'
                     '    ~ Immanuel Kant\n\n')
        resp.content_type = falcon.MEDIA_TEXT


app = application = falcon.API()

things = ThingsResource()
app.add_route("/things", things)

spec = APISpec(
    title="Things APP",
    version="0.0.1",
    openapi_version='3.0',
    plugins=[FalconPlugin(app)],
)

spec.path(resource=things)

print(json.dumps(spec.to_dict))
```

At running with (for example) gunicorn the OpenAPI-Specs get printed.

The docstrings of the functions have to be formated in YAML, so you will still have to write them. For more complex Datatypes using [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io) is recommended. It's not fully automated, but maybe it will do the Job for you.

EDIT: Fixed link

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some trouble with `falcon-apispec`.
For example it does not seem to be able to handle optional path parameters.

I ended up using [Spectree](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/0b01001001-spectree-python-documentation#falcon). Which seem to be a good match for me.

Answer (score 0):

falcon-apispec doesn't seem to be working with falcon 3+ versions.
I've tried the following fork : https://github.com/Javlopez/falcon-apispec

luckily it worked.
it's still unbelievable that there's no useful falcon swagger / openapi doc generator.